# Rellenar un array con números aleatorios SIN repetirse los números

Tags: c

tenía una duda con un programilla en C. Quiero rellenar un array unidimensional (vector) de 15 elementos con números aleatorios, pero no quiero que se repitan.

Los números generados son de 0 a 20 y utilizo una función entera existeElem que devuelve 1 si el elemento está en el vector y 0 en caso contrario. 
El problema está en qué no sé muy bien cómo aplicar esta función para que los números aleatorios no se repitan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define TAM 15
int  existeElem (int v[TAM], int longi, int num);
void generarVector (int v[TAM]);
void escribirVec (int v[TAM], int longi);

void main()
{
    int v[TAM], longi=TAM, num;

        generarVector(v);
        escribirVec(v, longi);

}

int existeElem(int v[TAM], int longi, int num)
{
    int i, enc=0;
    longi=TAM;

    for(i=0; i<longi && !enc; i++)
    {
        if(v[i]==num)
            enc=1;
    }

    return enc;
}

void generarVector (int v[TAM])
{
    int i, j, num, longi=TAM;
    srand((time)NULL);

    for (i=0; i<longi; i++)
    {
        v[i]=rand()%20+1;
        if(existeElem(v, longi, num))
            v[i]=     //no se muy bien como tratar con la funcion existeElem

    }

}

void escribirVec (int v[TAM], int longi)
{
    int i;
    longi=TAM;
    for(i=0; i<longi; i++)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

Comment: Si no quieres, que los números no se repitan, por definición no son aleatorios. Lo que realmente buscas es que el orden sea aleatorio, mas no los números.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz primero pensé lo mismo, pero el arreglo de resultado tiene 15 números no 21, por lo tanto no es suficiente con desordenar un array de 0-20, deberías también truncarlo. Mas alla, desordenar el arreglo y truncarlo, seria una solución mas _eficiente_ y esto se haría notorio en arreglos mucho mas grandes.

Comment: Efectivamente @rnd mi intención solo era recalcar el hecho del error al pensar que los números son aleatorios, no mostrar la solución completa. El problema mas grande es cuando el numero de elementos del arreglo se iguala al número de número de números disponibles. Los primeros números encontrarán fácil un lugar pero a medida que el arreglo se vaya llenando los números comenzarán a repetirse y cada vez tomará mas tiempo obtener los números que faltan para que no se repitan. El último casillero del arreglo tomará en promedio n/2 iteraciones para obtener el último número

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero te dire que haciendo `rand()%20+1` obtienes números del 1 al 20 y no de 0 a 20 (que son 21 números diferentes). Para obtener números del 0-20 deberías hacer `rand()%21`.

Segundo, la forma de invocar `srand` tiene un error: no debes hacer `srand((time)NULL);`, la forma correcta es `srand(time(NULL));`, ya que quieres invocar a la función `time` y lo que estas haciendo es *castear* NULL al tipo `time`, y al hacerlo, siempre le das la misma semilla al generador de números aleatorios, lo cual no quieres, pues serán menos aleatorios.

Luego, para hallar el un numero aleatorio que no exista en tu arreglo, puedes hacer es un `while(existeElem(v, longi, num = rand()%21));`

La explicacion:

- `while`: mientras que

  - `existeElem`: existe el elemento en array
  - `num = rand()%21`: establecer `num` con un valor aleatorio entre 0 y 20

Aquí `num` tiene 2 roles, primero se pasa como resultado para el `existeElem` y segundo queda establecido para luego usarse en la asignación de `v[i]`.

Función modificada:

```
void generarVector (int v[TAM])
{
    int i, j, num, longi=TAM;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<longi; i++)
    {
        while(existeElem(v, longi, num = rand()%21));
        v[i]= num;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ha quedado todo muy claro. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Tu solución tiene el problema que como cada vez que un numero aleatorio no te gusta, vuelves a buscar otro aleatorio, corres el peligro de encontrar siempre números que no te gustan, la posibilidad de quedarse "colgado" es poca pero si ya tienes 14 números, para el 15 solo te valdrán 7 de los 21 posibles, y todas las veces que repita hasta encontrar uno que valga es tiempo perdido.
Un ejemplo límite, quieres buscar 1.000.000 números aleatorios del 0 al 999.999 sin repetirse, en el último numero de todos, si solo falta por salir el '5' por ejemplo, estarás eligiendo números random de 0 a 999.999 hasta que salga el 5, no se si me explico...
La gracia del asunto es que lo haga a la primera.

Yo te aconsejo hacer un array de control que indique si ya ha salido un numero específico, y usar las posiciones que no han salido en vez del numero en si.

He hecho un ejemplo, no es una función, solo una muestra de a lo que me refiero:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(void){
    int lista[15];      // lista de 15 numeros aleatorios de 0 a 20 sin repetirse
    bool elegidos[21]; // ¿ya salio ese numero? (del 0 al 20)
    int posibles=21;
    int contador,posicion;
    int i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<21; i++) elegidos[i]=false; // Empieza que no se ha elegido ningun numero
    for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
        posicion=rand()%posibles+1;  // elige al azar una posicion entre los no elegidos (de 1 a 21)
        j=0;
        contador=0; // cuenta los numeros no elegidos que encuenta.
        while (contador<posicion) {         // Cuenta las posiciones no elegidas
            if (!elegidos[j++])contador++;  // Si el numero ya fue elegido se ignora
        }
        j--; // Cuando encuentra la posicion hace un j++ de mas.
        elegidos[j]=true;   // se marca la posicion como elegida
        posibles--;         // hay una posicion "no elegida" menos
        lista[i]=j;         // La posicion dentro la lista de elegidos es el numero a guardar
        std::cout << "lista["<<i<<"]= "<< j << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo comentar por una cuestión teorica al algoritmo de Arnau.

Su solución genera secuencias que matematicamente se puede demostrar que tienen todas la misma propabilidad de salir. (esto es BUENO).

Al igual que el algoritmo original que tambien la probabilidad de cada secuencia es la misma.

Pero el tiempo computacional del algoritmo de Arnau va a ser más o menos el mismo que el del algoritmo ORIGINAL debido al segundo bucle dentro del primero.

Un ejemplo límite, quieres buscar 1.000.000 números aleatorios del 0 al 999.999 sin repetirse, en el último numero de todos, si solo falta por salir el '567321' por ejemplo, estarás haciendo un bucle de tamaño 567321 hasta encontrar el que no ha sido elegido.

Para el penultimo idem...

Es un algoritmo cuadratico.

Existe un algoritmo lineal, (La gracia del asunto es que lo haga a la primera), que consiste en hacer permutaciones (swap) solo 1 dentro de cada iteración del for, sin mas bucles dentro.

El pseudocodigo seria:

```
for cada i entre 0 .. 20
    lista[i] = i;

k = 20;
for cada i entre 0 .. 14
    j = aleatorio (0..k)
    swap (lista, i, i+j)  // swap de indices
    k--;

 // la sublista: lista[0..14] contiene la secuencia aleatoria
```

Se puede demostrar matematicamente que todas las secuencias distintas tienen la misma probabilidad de salir:

Hay que demostrar esta cosas:

- Dada una secuencia que quiero que salga, existe una secuencia de 'j's, que la reproduce.
- Las posibles secuencias de 'j's tienen todas la misma probabilidad.
- En ese algoritmo, dada cualquier secuencia de 'j's me genera una secuencia de salida valida.
- El numero de posibles secuencias de j´s es el mismo que el numero de secuencias posibles. (BIYECCION entre secuencias de j´s y secuencias de salida)